# How does the warlock's Gaze of Two Minds eldritch invocation interact with senses other than vision/hearing, such as Blindsight?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, eldritch-invocations, special-senses

The warlock's [Gaze of Two Minds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#GazeofTwoMinds) eldritch invocation states that:

> [...] While perceiving through the other creature's senses, you benefit from any special senses possessed by that creature, and you are blinded and deafened to your own surroundings.

While using Gaze of Two Minds, can someone perceive their surroundings by senses other than vision or hearing, such as blindsight or smell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, other sense are fine. You are blinded and deafened, and that's all.

Blinded says: "blinded creature can't see", while Deafened says: "A deafened creature can't hear". So there's no mention of smell or taste or touch or Blindsight.

Note that while Blindsight has "sight" in the name, it is explicitly not sight, stating: "A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight". Darkvision and truesight are unfortunately still affected as they are both sight, darkvision says "Within a specified range, a creature with darkvision can see in darkness" and Truesight says: "A creature with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness"

You can see the rules for sight in the [vision and light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) section of the rules. Conditions are listed in the [appendix](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions).